# How to build a reinitializable lazy property in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, lazy-evaluation

This is what I'd like to do:

```
class MyObject {
    @Lazy volatile String test =  {
        //initalize with network access
    }()
}

def my = new MyObject()
println my.test

//Should clear the property but throws groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException
my.test = null 

//Should invoke a new initialization
println my.test
```

Unfortunately lazy fields are readonly fields in Groovy and clearing the property leads to an exception.

Any idea how to make a lazy field reinitializable without reimplementing the double checking logic provided by the @Lazy annotation?

**UPDATE:**

Considering soft=true (from the 1st answer) made me run a few tests:

```
class MyObject {
    @Lazy() volatile String test =  {
        //initalize with network access
        println 'init'
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        'test'
    }()
}

def my = new MyObject()
//my.test = null 
10.times { zahl ->
    Thread.start {println "$zahl: $my.test"}
}
```

Will have the following output on my Groovy console after approx 1 sec:

```
init
0: test
7: test
6: test
1: test
8: test
4: test
9: test
3: test
5: test
2: test
```

This is as expected (and wanted). Now I add `soft=true`and the result changes dramatically and it takes 10 seconds:

```
init
init
0: test
init
9: test
init
8: test
init
7: test
init
6: test
init
5: test
init
4: test
init
3: test
init
2: test
1: test
```

Maybe I'm doing the test wrong or soft=true destroys the caching effect completely. Any ideas?

Comment: Think this might be a bug in `soft=true`, I've updated my answer, and will do some more testing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you use the `soft` [attribute of Lazy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Lazy.html#soft), ie:

```
class MyObject {
  @Lazy( soft=true ) volatile String test =  {
    //initalize with network access
  }()
}
```

### edit

With `soft=true`, the annotation generates a setter and a getter like so:

```
private volatile java.lang.ref.SoftReference $test 

public java.lang.String getTest() {
    java.lang.String res = $test?.get()
    if ( res != null) {
        return res 
    } else {
        synchronized ( this ) {
            if ( res != null) {
                return res 
            } else {
                res = { 
                }.call()
                $test = new java.lang.ref.SoftReference( res )
                return res 
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setTest(java.lang.String value) {
    if ( value != null) {
        $test = new java.lang.ref.SoftReference( value )
    } else {
        $test = null
    }
}
```

Without `soft=true`, you don't get a setter

```
private volatile java.lang.String $test 

public java.lang.String getTest() {
    java.lang.Object $test_local = $test 
    if ( $test_local != null) {
        return $test_local 
    } else {
        synchronized ( this ) {
            if ( $test != null) {
                return $test 
            } else {
                return $test = { 
                }.call()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the variable is read-only. Not currently sure if this is intentional, or a side-effect of using `soft=true` though...

### Edit #2

This looks like it might be a bug in the implementation of Lazy with `soft=true`

If we change the getter to:

```
  public java.lang.String getTest() {
    java.lang.String res = $test?.get()
    if( res != null ) {
      return res 
    } else {
      synchronized( this ) {
        // Get the reference again rather than just check the existing res
        res = $test?.get()
        if( res != null ) {
          return res
        } else {
          res = { 
            println 'init'
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            'test'
          }.call()
          $test = new java.lang.ref.SoftReference<String>( res )
          return res 
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I think it's working...  I'll work on a bugfix

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. I wonder why, though, since the documentation says `soft=true`makes `test` a soft reference (which as I understand it lets it being considered for GC). Is the property's writability just a side effect then?

Comment: Just noticed: `soft=true` seems to erase the effect of `volatile` (thread safety with double checked locking)

Comment: Tim, what I tried when reading your updated answer is writing my own setter which uses `$test`internally. It's a hack, which requires internal knowledge but it works so far.